# Sql php 2 table's match

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I need the results where products.name whit a = before is in the alternates productsmap table.

products.name is a varchar 255 and a example result is

```
Haven
```

productsmap.alternates is a text and a example result is

```
=Havens go
=Haven 1
=Haven
```

this is one cel

I tried below but i don't get any results where i know i must get a result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT products.name 
FROM products 
WHERE CONCAT('=',products.name) in (select alternates from productsmap)
```

This query takes 1 minute and gives 0 rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fuzzy link between the two tables could be improved.  For example, this mapping table would perform better:

```
ProductName     Alternative
Haven           Havens go
Haven           Haven 1
Haven           Haven
```

To query your current table layout for `'Havens go'`, you could:

```
select  distinct p.name 
from    products p
join    productsmap pm
on      pm.alternative like '=' + p.name + '%'
where   pm.alternative = '=Havens go'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My sql skliks are not so good but what I want to do is get all the results from products.name that are in productsmap alternates cell. I can not change the current db as it is used by much more.

Comment: For all any row with a match, remove the `where` clause entirely